# Firebase notifications (only data) not receiving in Foreground

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hey everyone I've reading some problems that people have with Firebase and iOS notifications but seems that anybody is having the same issue.

For now I'm talking on **FOREGROUND** app state:

App receive the notification ever that have the parameter notification for exemple like this:

```
let notificationsParameters:[String:AnyObject] = [
        "to": "iphoneID",
        "content-available":true,
        "priority":"high",
// "notification" : [
//                "body" : "great match!",
//                "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
//                "icon" : "myicon"
//            ],
        "data" : [
            "Nick" : "Mario",
            "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
        ]
    ]
```

but once I removed the notification part app doesn't receive nothing, even keeping in foreground where as I see everyone should receive the notification.

I added priority high to receiving even closed/background and content-available, that I read is suppoused to solve my problem but is not the case.

Here you have the involved code:

**APP DELEGATE**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.



        GMSServices.provideAPIKey(Constants.GoogleMaps.APIKey)
        FIRApp.configure()


        /* NOTFICATIONS */

        let notificationsType:UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound]
        let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationsType, categories: nil)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.tokenRefreshNotification(_:)), name: kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification, object: nil)


        return true
    }
```

**NOTIFICATIONS (IN APP DELEGATE)**

As I understand this is what is suppouse that I will receive the data of the notification

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // Print message ID.
        print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")

        // Print full message.
        print("%@", userInfo)
    }

    func tokenRefreshNotification(notification:NSNotification) {
        let refreshedToken = FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()
        print("InstanceID token: \(refreshedToken)")

        connectToFCM()
    }

    func connectToFCM() {
        FIRMessaging.messaging().connectWithCompletion { (error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("GMS ERROR: \(error)")
            }
            else {
                print("Connected to GMS")
            }
        }
    }
```

**CALL TO FIREBASE NOTIFICATIONS**

```
func sendNotification() {

        let notificationsParameters:[String:AnyObject] = [
            "to": "iphoneID",
            "content-available":true,
            "priority":"high",
            //            "notification" : [
            //                "body" : "great match!",
            //                "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
            //                "icon" : "myicon"
            //            ],
            "data" : [
                "Nick" : "Mario",
                "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
            ]
        ]


        let URL = NSURL(string: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")!
        let URLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)

        URLRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        URLRequest.setValue("key=\(Constants.Firebase.NotificationsKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        URLRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let encoding = Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.JSON

        let encoded = encoding.encode(URLRequest, parameters: (notificationsParameters)).0
        Alamofire.request(encoded)
    }
```

Any further information you need just let me know!

Comment: have you got this resolved..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who have the same problem that me, one solution is setting notification parameters like this:

```
let notificationsParameters:[String:AnyObject] = [
            "to": "iphoneID",
            "content-available":true,
            "priority":"high",
           "notification" : [
               "sound" : " "
           ],
            "data" : [
                "Nick" : "Mario",
                "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
            ]
        ]
```

You won't receive the notification when app is killed but you will be able to receive only data notification when is in foreground and background, good luck!

Answer (score 5):

You were on the right track, but need an underscore instead of hyphen in the `content_available` parameter. No need to use the `notification` object if you want a data only (silent) notification using FCM.

Eg, in your FCM send request body:

```
{
    "to": "iPhoneID",
    "content_available": true,
    "priority": "high",
    "data": {
        "nick": "mario",
        "room": "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. content_available made all the difference. The third paragraph in this link is missing this information: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive#handle-data-messages-in-foregrounded-apps